# Uso de ProgressBar en Angular y .NET

Tags: c#, angular, typescript, .net, progressbar

estoy realizando un sistema en Angular y .NET en el cual subo archivos y quiero agregarle una barra de progreso, he logrado mostrarlo con un dialog:

```
<p-dialog [(visible)]="dProgressBar" [style]="{width: '50vw', 'text-align': 'end'}" [modal]="true"
    header="Cargando...">
    <ng-template pTemplate="content">
        <div>
            <p-progressBar *ngIf="progressBarVisible" [value]="value"></p-progressBar>
        </div>
    </ng-template>
</p-dialog>
```

Y en mi Componente tengo declarado:

```
  value = 0;
  progressBarVisible = false;
```

En el mismo componente tengo una función que realiza una petición hacía mi servicio de la siguiente manera:

```
getArchivo(formData: FormData) {
this.blockedPanel = true;
this.dProgressBar = true;

this.progressBarVisible = true;
this._http.post('/Files', formData).then((res: any) => {
  if (res && !res.error) {
    this.blockedPanel = false;
    this.progressBarVisible = false;
    this.dProgressBar = false;
//Resto de código...
```

En donde mi servicio:

```
public async post( method: string, payload: any = {}): Promise<any> {
      this.http.post(`${this.apiUrl}${method}`, payload, {
          reportProgress: true,
          observe: 'events',
        })
        .subscribe(
          (event) => {
            if (event.type === HttpEventType.UploadProgress && event.total !== undefined) {
              // This is an upload progress event. Compute and show the % done:
              const progress = Math.round(100 * event.loaded / event.total);
              this.progresoSubject.next(progress);
            } else if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
              console.log('File is completely uploaded!');
              console.log(event.body);
            }
          },
          (error) => {
            this.progresoSubject.next(-1); // Notificar error al componente
            this.message.add({
              severity: 'error',
              summary: 'Error al consultar',
              detail: error.message,
              life: 5000,
            });
          }
        );
      }
```

Hasta este punto se muestra bien la barra, pero está llena antes de siquiera entrar al método, lo he podido confirmar ya que agregue brakpoints para poder visualizar mejor el progreso y no funciona.

Si alguien me pudiera brindar algún ejemplo ya que he investigado y no veo que haya que agregar algo del lado del servidor.

Saludos y muchas gracias.

EDICIÓN

Estuve leyendo en otras partes en internet que se puede hacer uso de WebSocket o SignalR, solo que no he sabido implementarlo.

Mi código en mi backend a donde entra la petición es la siguiente:

```
[RequestSizeLimit(10L * 1024L * 1024L * 1024L * 1024L)]
    [RequestFormLimits(MultipartBodyLengthLimit = 10L * 1024L * 1024L * 1024L * 1024L)]
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Post([FromForm] InputModel data)
    {
        object datas = new object();
        //mov_ArchivosEntes arr = new mov_ArchivosEntes();
        var postFiles = await _uploadFiles.PostUploadFiles(data);

        try
        {
            //string code = JwsToken.GetTokenCode(Request);
            //if (code == null) return Unauthorized();
             var arr = (List<mov_ArchivosEntes>)Convert.ChangeType(postFiles, typeof(List<mov_ArchivosEntes>));

            var checkFiles = await _layoutData.GetVerify(arr,data);
            
            return Ok(checkFiles);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return BadRequest(postFiles);
        }
    }
```

Aquí se puede ver que primero entra a procesar el archivo en el método `PostUploadFiles` y después pasa por diferentes instrucciones para validar los campos que entran desde el front para validar a que tabla entrara y validar si se tienen los datos correctos.